# VB.NET Nothing evaluating to False

Tags: vb.net

Consider the following VB.NET code:

```
Sub ObjectTest()
    Dim active As Object = Nothing

    If active = False Then
        Console.WriteLine("false")
    End If

    If active = True Then
        Console.WriteLine("true")
    End If

    If active = Nothing Then
        Console.WriteLine("nothing")
    End If
End Sub
```

the output I get on the console is

```
false
nothing
```

This means

```
If active = False
```

is succeeding. How can this be? active is set to nothing so how can it be false? It is not false, it is nothing. We know this because the

```
If active = Nothing
```

condition succeeds.

Incidentally, if I change the code to:

```
Sub ObjectTest()
    Dim active As Object = vbnull

    If active = False Then
        Console.WriteLine("false")
    End If

    If active = True Then
        Console.WriteLine("true")
    End If

    If active = vbnull Then
        Console.WriteLine("null")
    End If
End Sub
```

The only output I get is "null" Clearly in VB.NET then, "nothing" does not mean "null"

What is causing the condition to think active is equal to false?

Comment: Set `Option Strict` to ON. Then you can't switch types as you wish.

Comment: Apologies for the duplicate. The link you have posted makes perfect sense

Comment: In my code I used object because the result I am looking for is a boolean that could be null. The way round the issue above is to decalre Dim active as boolean?

Comment: "Dim active as boolean?"  is a Boolean that can be null. Also, you should use IS and not = when comparing with Nothing

Comment: Changed that too as I got a VS warning